# Show submenu with CSS without using an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a question regarding showing a submenu with CSS. 
I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/">Test1</a>
    <a href="/">Test2</a>
    <div class="submenu-wrapper">
      <a href="/">Test3</a>
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="/">Submenu1</a>
        <a href="/">Submenu2</a>
      </div>      
    </div>
    <a href="/">Test4</a>
</div>
```

Due to implementation restriction I can not change my structure to, for example a `<ul>` format.

I did some research on the web to find out how I could show my submenu by using CSS. I tried the following thing:

```
.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover > .submenu{display:block;}
```

Can anyone tell my why this does not work and how could I solve this, with respect to my current implementation.

Full code here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xrtjngdr/)

PS. Any answers like use bootstrap or transform your menu to a `<ul>` format is not what I am looking ;)

Comment: Try `.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover +  .submenu{display:block;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover > .submenu{display:block;}
```

Your .submenu is not inside the `a`. You could use the sibling selector:

```
.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover + .submenu{display:block;}
```

But to make the submenu usable,  make sure your .submenu-wrapper has the same height as its content (by giving it a fixed height or an `:after{clear:both;}` and do this:

```
.navigation .submenu-wrapper:hover .submenu{display:block;}
```

Since your `.submenu` is absolutely positioned, you also need to position its parent, or else `.submenu` will fall off the screen (because you gave it `top:100%` relative to body). Like this:

```
.navigation .submenu-wrapper {position: relative;}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrtjngdr/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this does not work properly. You can not select any sub menu items anymore. Whenever you want to hover the submenu closes

Comment: That's because when you're hovering over the submenu, you're not hovering over the `a`. If you give the submenu-wrapper a height like in my second solution, you will be able to hover over the submenu.

Comment: Thanks for you updated fiddle! That is exactly what I wanted. Just one more question. I updated your Fiddle and I was wondering do you know how to set the white background full 100% on hover on a sub item? [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xrtjngdr/6/)

Comment: Sure: `.submenu a {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing

`.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover > .submenu{display:block;}`

To `.navigation .submenu-wrapper a:hover + .submenu{display:block;}`

You also have to add

```
.submenu:hover{
  display:block;
}
```

Because if you want to click on your submenu, the links will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Just a few small changes and you're golden.

See the comments in the code below for your changes.

```css
.navigation {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
.navigation .submenu-wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* add relative position */
}
.navigation > a,
.navigation .submenu-wrapper a {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 5.5px;
  padding-bottom: 8.5px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none; /* display none */
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #245d94;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.navigation a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #245d94;
}
.navigation a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e36c0a;
}
.navigation .submenu-wrapper:hover .submenu { /* As you want the menu to remain open when you move to the submenu */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/">Test1</a>
  <a href="/">Test2</a>
  <div class="submenu-wrapper">
    <a href="/">Test3</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <a href="/">Submenu1</a>
      <a href="/">Submenu2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="/">Test4</a>
</div>
```